# How to get line below second to last instance of a string in a file

Tags: bash, grep, instance, tail

I am trying to obtain the line below the second to last instance of a string in a file, but the tail +2 command doesn't seem to be working to find the second to last instance. When I try the code below:

```
for i in `find . -name "aims.out" -type f`;
do
     grep -l 'grep -A 1 "string"' $i
     T1=$(grep 'string' $i|tail +2)
     grep -l 'grep -A 2 "string"' $i
     T2=$(grep 'string' $i|tail +2)
    
done
```

I receive the error "tail: cannot open ‘+2’ for reading: No such file or directory", and I get the last instance. Any suggestions?

Sample input:

```
 | i_atom:           25
  | i_atom:           26
  |
 sum osc_str                     NaN
 n_elec   106.000000000000
  Eigenvalues TDA BSE.
  State    Eigenvalue [Ha]    Eigenvalue [eV]    Oscillator Strength
      1          -0.152200          -4.141573             NaN
      2          -0.136095          -3.703339             NaN
      3          -0.133551          -3.634100             NaN
      4          -0.128803          -3.504903             NaN
      5          -0.124969          -3.400571             NaN
```

Sample output:

```
-4.141573
```

EDIT: solved with

```
T1=$(cat aims.out| grep -A 1 "string" | tail -n 4 | head -n 1 | cut -c 36-46 )
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Try `tail -n +2`. What does `tail --help` output?

Comment: After some review of the help, I came up with a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To print the line after the penultimate occurrence of the pattern `foo`, you could do:

```
awk 'h{h=0; b=a; a=$0} /foo/ {h=1}END {print b}' input
```

To incorporate that into `find`, you could do:

```
find . -name aims.out -type f -exec awk 'h{h=0; b=a; a=$0} 
    /string/ {h=1}END {print b}' {} \;
```